# add bootstrap to meteor package

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, meteor-packages

meteor beginner here.

I have a local package (a personal variation of lukemadera:image-picker) in my meteor folder under

> packages\my-package

I'd like to use bootstrap styling within that package (specifically: apply the bs-grid to the content) - how do I do this most easily?

I integrated the package using `api.use('twbs:bootstrap')`, and added it with `meteor add twbs:bootstrap`. However, somehow the bootstrap styles are not applied to my (partly dynamically added) content.

Do I need to import it somewhere else so that I can use the different style classes?

Comment: Do you target for a specific bootstrap version?

Comment: @Jankapunkt not specifically at the moment, but it would be nice to have the possibility

Comment: Welcome to SO! You very probably need to share a sample of a page where you try to use Bootstrap styles, for people to be able to help you more specifically. The [help for asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and in particular about [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) provide some guidance.

Comment: I managed to apply the styles, apparently something did not load properly...
but thanks for the warm welcome, @ghybs - will try to pose a more specific question next time ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ways to do this;

1. You need to go to location `your_project_folder/.meteor/packages` file you need to add line `twbs:bootstrap` and start meteor server with the command `meteor`, if the server was up, will auto-detect changes to the `packages` file and import the stuff for you.
2. stop the server using `CTRL + C` 2 times, then run command `meteor add twbs:bootstrap` and then start server.

By this, you can do everything that is possible in bootstrap.

Comment: I have done this, however none of the styling seems to be activated within the content I load dynamically with my local package - do I have to somehow import the CSS files individually?

Comment: no, it is imported by default in the package Or you can put bootstrap folder in `client` folder itself, everything gets loaded by default.